# An good examples of a client-server setup in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, resources, client-server

I'm trying to learn how to do some very simple client-server application programming.

Basically, I want to make a program (the server) that listens and waits, and when a commend is sent it will run a batch file or execute a line of code.

The client will just ask for the ip and send the command when a button is pushed.

Shouldn't be too hard right? So what are some good resources that you've used to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to dig into WCF, the *Windows Communication Foundation*. That's the state-of-the art for writing .NET components that need to communicate over some kind of network. Googling for `wcf introduction` yields various tutorials and examples to this topic.